# Problem related to i18n with Struts application

Tags: tomcat

I am doing a small project on i18n with Struts, using MyEclipse 8.6.

Whenever I try to run through MyEclipse, Tomcat shows the following errors:

> 8 Feb, 2011 1:00:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
>       INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Genuitec\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013\bin;C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Genuitec\Common\plugins\com.genuitec.eclipse.easie.tomcat.myeclipse_8.6.0.me201007231647\tomcat\bin
>       8 Feb, 2011 1:00:15 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
>       SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
>       java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:359)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:185)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:141)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:496)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:177)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1059)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:677)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:792)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:518)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:260)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
>       8 Feb, 2011 1:00:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>
> *[Several dozen more lines redacted]*

What am I doing wrong, here?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Struts, Java or JSP.

Tomcat is failing to start up because something is already using the port that Tomcat is trying to bind to (probably port 8080).  You can't run two things on the same port at the same time.

Find out what else is using port 8080, and close it down.

Comment: ...or change the Tomcat port to one which isn't already used by another service.